# How can I use the default theme from 12.10 in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, themes

I really like the changes that was made to the default theme in 12.10. However 12.10 keeps on loosing the ability to see my braodcom wifi card and I am experiencing a lot of graphical glitches as well.

12.04 is rock solid and I use this for my production work. Please tell me there is a safe and easy way to import the new theme from 12.10 into 12.04.

Thanks in advance,

George

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `/usr/share/themes` and copy any theme you want to your home directory under `.themes`. I'm not sure if a theme from upper version will work properly ;)

Comment: Thanks your method worked great, the theme is broken in 12.04 though :(